# How to write text from HTML input on picture with PHP

Tags: php, image

Got this HTML code:

```html
<input class="text" name="Chipnummer" type="text" value="adding text" />
```

I want to save it on my picture like this

my php:

```php
$text['adding text'];

imagefttext($image, 60, 0, 650, 270, $red, 'verdana.ttf',['adding text']);

$filename       = 'stamtavle1.png';
```

but it is not working ??

i want to save the picture with the  `$hvalpe_data['navn1']` as name.

```php
$filename = $hvalpe_data['navn1'].png;
```

It is getting a file instead of a png

I really need you help.

```
<div class="image">
<img src="image/stamtavle.png" alt="" style=" width:1200;">

     <h2><?=$hvalpe_data['navn1'];?></h2> 
     <h4><input class="text" name="Chipnummer" type="text" value="Chipnummer"></h4>
     <text><input class="text" name="Stambogsnummer" type="text" value="Stambogsnummer"></text>
     <text1><?=$hvalpe_data['hvalp_farve'];?><text1>
     <text2><?=$hvalpe_data['firstname'] . ' ' . $hvalpe_data['lastname'];?><text2>
     <text3><?=$hvalpe_data['adresse'];?></text3>
```

```
$POST['chpinummer'];

$hvalpe_data['navn1'];
$hvalpe_data['firstname'] . ' ' . $hvalpe_data['lastname'];
$hvalpe_data['adresse'];

$image = imagecreatefrompng('stamtavle.png');
imagealphablending($image, true);

$black  = imagecolorallocate($image, 150,0, 0);

// imagefttext("Image", "Font Size", "Rotate Text", "Left Position", "Top Position", "Font Color", "Font Name", "Text To Print");

imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $POST['chpinummer']);
imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $hvalpe_data['firstname'] . ' ' . $hvalpe_data['lastname']);   
imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 440, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $hvalpe_data['adresse']);
imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 490, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $hvalpe_data['post']);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?is there anything in your logs that would suggest an issue? do the image and font files exist? Can you provide a bare bones (or at least the whole) script you have the issue with as the code provided isn't valid code. If you provide this information you will be more likely to get a helpful response. You can find more information on improving your questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For your form text submission, depending on the `method` of either `post` or `get`, you will need to use the corresponding php super global. `$_POST['Chipnummer']` or `$_GET['Chipnummer']` to retrieve the `"adding text"` value. Then you need to use string concatenation (`.`), to combine the variable and extension string.  `$filename = $hvalpe_data['navn1'] . '.png';` I would post as an answer but we need to see a minimally reproducible version of your code.

Comment: has addint this to the php $GET['chpinummer']; and this imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $GET['chpinummer']); but it is not working :-(

Comment: @michaelnielsen you need the `$_` in `$_GET` or if your form method is post its `$_POST`. Additionally PHP is case-sensitive, since the input is `name="Chipnummer"`, you need `$_GET['Chipnummer']`  or `$_POST['Chipnummer']`

Comment: do you mene like this ??  html:<input class="text" name=$_POST['Chipnummer'] type="text" value="Chipnummer" > an in the php: $_POST['chpinummer']; and imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $$black, 'verdana.ttf', $_POST['chpinummer']);........ that is not working

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntactical issues with your PHP code.

First, the PHP super global for retrieving form data should be either `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depending on your `<form method="post">` if the `method` attribute is missing or is set to `method="get"` you will need to use `$_GET`.

Second, PHP is case-sensitive when accessing array indexes, so since you are using `<input name="Chpinummer">` your PHP needs to correspond with the form field name casing. So you would use `$_POST['Chpinummer']` to retrieve the submitted value, provided the form method is indeed `method="post"`.

Third, using `$$` with a PHP variable will cause the value to return a reference to a [variable variable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). Since you are declaring the `imagecolorallocate` color as `$black` you need to use `$black` not `$$black`.

Lastly, there is no way to know what values are declared as `$hvalpe_data`, since you did not provide an example in your question. So for brevity I have removed the references to them to focus only on the specific issue.

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('stamtavle.png');
imagealphablending($image, true);

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 0, 0);

imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $black, 'verdana.ttf', $_POST['Chpinummer']);
```

---

Furthermore, it is best-practice to specify the full (absolute) path to reference file resources, ie: `/full/path/to/file`. If your file resources are within the same directory as your PHP script. ie: `/var/www/public/script.php` and `/var/www/public/stamtavle.png` you should use `__DIR__ . '/stamtavle.png'`.
For more details see [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng(__DIR__ . '/stamtavle.png');
imagealphablending($image, true);

$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 150, 0, 0);

imagefttext($image, 40, 0, 850, 390, $black, __DIR__ . '/verdana.ttf', $_POST['Chpinummer']);
```